# WordPress: Assigning widgets to individual pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Are there any plugins or hacks that allow assigning widgets to individual pages?

**EDIT:**
Using self-hosted (.org) 2.8.4

An example of use would be: when you're editing a page in the admin, you'd ideally have the ability to assign widgets to that specific page. The default WP behavior is more "all or nothing" in that you assign widgets to the global sidebar and that's it... all pages get the exact same set of widgets... no "per page" assignment of widgets.

The [Widget Logic plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) essentially achieves the desired result with a backwards approach, but it doesn't seem to work with the [Rich Text Widget plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rich-text-widget/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the [Widget Context plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-context/) which does what I need.

Answer (score 2):

There are several good ones. Display Widgets is my favorite. Widget Locationizer is perhaps more robust, but takes longer to manage. You can't go wrong with either one.

Comment: +1 For Display Widgets, Widget Context didn't work for me on WP 3.0.3

Comment: Display Widgets let's you easily choose specific pages and categories by using check boxes, but Widget Context does not (unless you type the URI manually)... So +1 for Display Widgets!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugins that would give this functionality, but you might want to look at page templates here:  [WP Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)

With this route its more of a hack, as you can't use the CMS backend to manage your widgets.  You would have to manually cut and paste the code of the widget into your page.

Answer (score 0):

How about [WP Page Widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-page-widget/):

> Select widgets for each page / post / custom post type. For every
>   single page / post / custom post type we can select which widgets to
>   show.

This does it "the right way", i.e. when you edit a page you can choose which widgets to show on that page.