# how do i disable wordpress widget for specific page?

Tags: php, widget, wordpress

I am new to WordPress 3.6.1. I have apply quick contact module into my site, but it shows in every page. how do I able to disable that widget from contact us page? I had try from page.php file but I am failed to implement what i want.

Comment: look at this post, it may be able to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303803/wordpress-assigning-widgets-to-individual-pages

Comment: Use widget logic plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also install [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/) it has a [Widget visibility](http://jetpack.me/support/widget-visibility/) control, where you choose where you want a widget to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [**Widget Logic**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/) plugin just put your if condition in text field

> This plugin gives every widget an extra control field called "Widget
>   logic" that lets you control the pages that the widget will appear on.
>   The text field lets you use WP's [**Conditional Tags**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), or any
>   general PHP code